# Very strange bug in this 1 line function

Tags: swift

So I stumbled onto something really weird.

Here is a 1 line function

```
@objc func foo(value: Int = 1) {
    print("value is \(value)")
}
```

I'm gonna set up a tap gesture in `viewDidLoad` to call that function:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Here's the `handleTap` method. Note how I call `foo` without any arguments.

```
@objc func handleTap() {
    foo()
}
```

As you'd expect, it prints out a `1` every time.

**Enter The Dragon**

Here's where it gets weird. Let's change `handleTap` to only post a notification. And we'll add an observer for that notification in `viewDidLoad` to call `foo`, like so.

The notification:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let didSomething = Notification.Name("didSometing")
}
```

The new `handleTap` method:

```
@objc func handleTap() {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .didSomething, object: nil)
}
```

And our addition to `viewDidLoad`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(foo), name: .didSomething, object: nil)
```

Now every time I tap, I get all kinds of values, here's what my output looks like:

```
value is 10748457248
value is 10748611248
value is 10748564928
value is 10748456000
value is 10748564256
value is 10748612688
value is 10748611824
value is 10748609616
value is 10748612496
value is 10748564592
```

Now if I change the notification observation to call a new method `fooCaller` (which is just a method that calls `foo()`), then I get all 1's.

So I figure it's something to do with obj-c, selectors and arguments, but thing is that my foo can be called without any arguments, like `foo()`, so I would reasonably expect `#selector(foo)` to have the same behaviour but it doesn't, and I don't know why.

In actuality, my function (which is represented here by foo) never took any arguments and was only called from notification observations. Then I later needed to call foo directly, passing something. So I gave it a default value so as not to disturb the current use of foo elsewhere, but it opened up the dark dimension instead.

Comment: `10748457248` etc is the Notification. It is different because the Notification is a different object each time it is posted. If you don’t need to see it, ignore it instead of printing it. (I could explain at more length but it’s all rather boring unfortunately.)

Comment: @matt Oh, hmm. I had no idea what it was; when I made the 'value' parameter to be of type Double then it was always the same, 1.6080749353e-314 every time it was triggered by a notification. I was using this value to do something meaningful; foo(value: 5) would do some work after 5s, and I wanted to keep the notification triggered foo()'s to do some work after 1s (default value). That 1s timing got messed up for the notification triggered calls when I made foo take a parameter with a default value. Didn't know the notification is arriving in as the parameter. Thanks Mr. Neuburg :)

Comment: No, the stuff about the default value is a red herring. You could delete `= 1` but you'd get the same result.

Comment: I'll actually explain it a bit further in an answer. But sorry, it isn't magic, dark or otherwise...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There *is* sort of a bug, in the sense that, in my opinion, your code should not compile. And it does indeed, as you suspect, have to do with the tricky interface between Objective-C and Swift.

Let's look at the declaration of `addObserver` in Objective-C:

```
- (void)addObserver:(id)observer selector:(SEL)aSelector 
     name:(NSNotificationName)aName object:(id)anObject;
```

According to the docs, the `selector` must refer to a method that has

> one and only one argument (an instance of NSNotification)

That's because the NSNotification can contain important information, such as its `userInfo`, that you might need to receive.

In other words, your `foo`, if it is to be the method called by the notification center to let you know of the notification, should have this signature:

```
@objc func foo(_ notification: Notification) {
```

And if it did, you'd be able to do stuff like this:

```
@objc func foo(_ notification: Notification) {
    print(notification) // name = didSomething, object = nil, userInfo = nil
}
```

Great. But your `foo` does not have that signature; it types its parameter as Int instead. This is not identically what you have, but it might as well be:

```
@objc func foo(_ value: Int) {
```

Now, in my opinion, that should not be permitted. If you declare your `foo` that way, then when the time comes to use it as the selector...

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(foo), name: .didSomething, object: nil)
```

...the compiler should complain: "No, you can't do that, `foo` has the wrong type as its parameter!" But it doesn't.

So the Notification object arrives and is interpreted as an Int in accordance with its memory location — and that is what you are printing.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Neuburg! I never knew that until now 

Comment: Yeah, sorry the truth isn't more exciting. It's like a card trick to which you've been told the answer; the magic goes away completely.

Comment: Btw I've filed a bug report with the Swift folks, FWIW. As I've said, in my view the job of the Swift compiler is to save you from yourself in this situation. If you had typed `value`  as String you'd compile at compile time and crash at runtime. If I wanted that to happen I'd still be writing code in Objective-C.

Comment: Oh I don't know Mr. Neuburg, I guess the magic just moves to the explanation . Thanks for filing the bug report, those would be nice compile errors to have.

Answer (score 1):

Your console log print these numbers because of this line:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(foo), name: .didSomething, object: nil)
```

This function is passing the `Notification` as a parameter which causes these logs. Modify your function to receive the notification and handle it.

```
@objc func foo(notification: Notification) {
    print("received notification: \(notification)")
}
```

Try passing the `foo` function as parameter for selector in tapGestureRecognizer, like this:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(foo))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

You'll see a similar result it's because because here the UITapGestureRecognizer is being passed to the `foo` function.

Comment: Oh, just saw that maybe I'll add a bit more explanation.